# Facebook Share showing incorrect info when the debugger is correct

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-share

First post on StackOverflow, so please forgive any protocol lapses!

I've found similar problems to the one below elsewhere on SO, but none that's an exact match, nor a solution that hits the spot.

I have a client site with FB Share and Like buttons, all of which work perfectly on straightforward named pages. In the case of the shop and blog pages I need to use a querystring, which works perfectly on other sites, but not this one! I've run the FB Debugger on the affected pages and all looks hunky dory.

Here are two example pages with the problem:
http://www.fabniki.com/productdetail?pid=251 and http://www.fabniki.com/blogdetail?id=327&p=1.

In the case of the shop item, the text Facebook is showing isn't even on the page. I've tried clearing cache, forcing an FB cache refresh etc.

My own site uses a similar querystring system for my blog, and this works absolutely fine with Facebook shares and likes.

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was - unsurprisingly - entirely of my own making. I'd allowed myself to get bogged down in the debugger, which looks at the exact URL you paste into its input field. If you're sufficiently idiotic, it may not occur to you to check if this is the actual value being passed to FB by your Like and Share buttons. Doh!

Thanks to some excellent support from FB developers, the problem was spotted and corrected with only minor dents to my ego.

I wanted to answer my own question, a) to avoid wasting people's time and b) to give Facebook Support a bit of appreciation for a change!